# Avoid hourglass after calling CreateProcess

Tags: windows, winapi, createprocess, busy-cursor

In my Win32 app I embed ffplay.exe for video preview. It works great but each time I start a preview the cursor becomes "busy", i.e. arrow+hourglass. I want to avoid that.

Comment: Have you considered that this is happening because the application is "busy" doing background processing?

Comment: @Cody Gray: That's actually the default behavior in Windows and it's quite annoying in many scenarios including the one OP mentions.

Comment: @sharptooth: I think it's a perfectly sensible default behavior. Overriding it strikes me as a mistake. The hard disk light on the front of my computer blinks when I'm hitting the disk, too. But I haven't covered that up with black electrical tape.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Yes, it is sensible default behavior and it makes sense most of the time, but it is *sometimes* annoying.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set `STARTF_FORCEOFFFEEDBACK` flag in `dwFlags` member of `STARTUP_INFO` struct that you pass to `CreateProcess()`.